# Why do I get the exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation?

Tags: c#, encryption, xamarin.forms, rsa

In a page of xamarin forms application, I need to store what the user enters in an encrypted format, so I used application properties and RSA encryption, but when I open the app and try to move to the settings page, the app crashes saying: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation'. Please let me know why I get this error and how to fix this?

This is my RSA encryption class:

```
          class RsaEncryption
{
    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    private RSAParameters _privateKey;
    private RSAParameters _publicKey;

    public RsaEncryption()
    {
        _privateKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
        _publicKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);
    }

    public string GetPublicKey()
    {
        var stringWriter=new StringWriter();
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, _publicKey);

        return stringWriter.ToString();

    }

    public string EncryptField(string plainText)
    {
        csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        csp.ImportParameters(_publicKey);

        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
        var cypher = csp.Encrypt(data, false);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cypher);
    }

    public string DecryptField(string cypherText)
    {
        var databytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cypherText);

        csp.ImportParameters(_privateKey);
        var plainText = csp.Decrypt(databytes, false);

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel class:

```
       class SettingsViewModel
{
    private const string UsernameKey = "Username";
    private const string PasswordKey = "Password";
    private const string EndPointKey = "EndPoint";

    RsaEncryption rsaEncryption=new RsaEncryption();

    public string Username
        {
        get 
        {
            if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(UsernameKey))
                return (Application.Current.Properties[UsernameKey].ToString());

            return "";
        }

        set
        {
            Application.Current.Properties[UsernameKey]=rsaEncryption.EncryptField(value);
        }
        }

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(PasswordKey))
                return rsaEncryption.DecryptField(Application.Current.Properties[PasswordKey].ToString());

            return "";
        }

        set
        {
            Application.Current.Properties[PasswordKey] = rsaEncryption.EncryptField(value);
        }
    }

    public string EndPoint
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(EndPointKey))
                return rsaEncryption.DecryptField(Application.Current.Properties[EndPointKey].ToString());

            return "";
        }

        set
        {
            Application.Current.Properties[EndPointKey] = rsaEncryption.EncryptField(value);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: TargetInvocationException can mean that an exception was thrown in code that is being invoked using Reflection rather than being called directly. The actual exception should be present as an InnerException property of the TargetInvocationException. Even if that's not what's happening here, adding the InnerException and StackTrace properties of the exception to your question will make it easier to answer.